# Nested and dynamically created directives in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, directive

I am stuck with this for quite a long time.

In a directive, I would like to create another directive on the fly, based on a function. Instead of having 4 directive declarations, I would prefer to create a new directive in each 'tab' directive, that is to say each time a tab attribute is set in a DOM element.

Here is a part of the code (config is a factory that is use to configure some stuff) :

```
.directive('tab', function(config) {
    return {
        require: '^panelHandler',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.addPane(scope);
            scope.select = function() {
                ctrl.select(scope);
            };
        },
    };
})
.directive('page1', directiveConfigurer('page1.html'))
.directive('page2', directiveConfigurer('page2.html'))
.directive('page3', directiveConfigurer('page3.html'))
.directive('page4', directiveConfigurer('page4.html'));

function directiveConfigurer(fileName) {
    newDirective.$inject = ['config'];

    return newDirective;

    function newDirective(config) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: true,
            templateUrl: config.filesDirectory + fileName,
        };
        return directive;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT :

Config...

```
angular.module('appLogic', ['socket-factory', 'data-factory', 'panelHandler-module'])
    .factory('config', function() {
        return {
            filesDirectory : '../../templates/pages/',
            fieldsNumber : 5,
        };
    });
```

and what I need...

```
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.addPane(scope);


        //.directive('page' + number, directiveConfigurer(name))


        scope.select = function() {
            ctrl.select(scope);
        };
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the directives are essentially the same, except for the template url, then you can just create a single directive and provide the concrete url path as an attribute:

```
<page src="page1.html">
```

To do that, use a function for `templateUrl` property of the directive definition object:

```
.directive("page", function(){
  return {

    templateUrl: function(tElem, tAttr){
      return "/base/path/" + tAttr.src;
    },
    //...

  };
});
```

Comment: It is an interesting solution, I did not know we could do that. But in this case I won't be able to resolve my problem this way. 'tab' directives create and control my sidebar nav buttons, and for each button added in the sidebar, I want to create a new directive with its own template which will be displayed in another part of the html template.

Comment: @A.R., this solution allows you to specify a different template. It's not clear what you mean by "create". Do you mean "define" a new directive, or do you mean add a directive to the DOM: `<my-dir></my-dir>`.

Comment: Currently, my directives are added to the DOM (<page1></page1>...). I have to define them, and I want to do this for each 'tab' directive that is defined. The purpose is to have a new directive definition each time I add a 'tab'.

Comment: @A.R., a directive is a piece of functionality. It is defined statically, once. You can use a different template dynamically - like I showed, based on your question. I'm not sure what currently the problem is. Why do you think you need to "create a new directive"?

Comment: What would be perfect in the end is to juste have to create new buttons in the side bar to see added the corresponding element (html tag + directive definition), with a new path set with an attribute.

Comment: @A.R., I think you misunderstand what directives are... Nothing in your question or comments addresses the issue you are having that you think necessitates what you think you are looking for (i.e. creating directives on the fly). Try not to muddy the waters - one question per one issue. This question seems to be about how to select a different template for a directive. If you have another issue not specified in your question, create a new question

Comment: I never spoke about another issue. You asked me some details, and the only way I thought I could answer you was to give you these details, which are the final purpose of what I'm doing. Anyway, you say it better, I am looking for a way to make a link between a template and a DOM element. But the 'tab' directive concerns a very different element from the one really concerned by the new template. On one side are tab buttons, and on the other sides content elements.

Comment: @A.R., again... directives are defined statically. There is no apparent use case whereby one would need to create at "run-time" directives `page1`, `page2`, ..,`pageN`. You can create all of them in a loop, but it has to be done before the app is bootstapped. But nothing in your question suggests why you think you need it. In fact, the proper way is to create a directive to encompass some piece of functionality, and allow for the template to be defined as an attribute, to make it dynamic

Comment: Statically, of course. Hmm. I could use a loop, for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) and define 4 directives for the DOM elements I created. But it seems a bit hard coded. What if I add a fifth page ? I need to add a sidebar button, then a DOM element, then modify the loop... By defining a nested directive, I was looking for a way to define a directive each time a 'tab' is set. A new tab would simply define a new 'sub'-directive for my new element.

Comment: @A.R., in your question you attempt to add `.directive` in the `link` function - that is anything *but* statically. I'm sorry, your question is either unclear, or more likely, doesn't make sense as an objective. I gave you an approach you can take.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time. I will think about what you propose :).